# Comparing two apparently identical levels from factors

Tags: r, xgboost

I have two dataframe columns that have apparently identical factors, but they don't:

```
levels(train$colA)
## [1] "I am currently using (least once over the last 2 weeks)"
## [2] "I have never tried nor used"
## [3] "I have tried or used at some point in time"

levels(test$colA)
## [1] "I am currently using (least once over the last 2 weeks)"
## [2] "I have never tried nor used"
## [3] "I have tried or used at some point in time"

                                                      
levels(train$colA) == levels(test$colA)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I have tried comparing both sentences and actually they are equal:

```
"I am currently using (least once over the last 2 weeks)" == "I am currently using (least once over the last 2 weeks)"
## [1] TRUE
```

I am trying to apply xgboost trained model to test data. Trained model comes from `train` dataframe. Now I am trying to apply it to `test`, but with no success, as I get the error that `test` has a new factor.

Edited:

Here is the output of dput():

```
dput(head(train$colA))
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("I am currently using (least once over the last 2 weeks)", "I have never tried nor used"
"I have tried or used at some point in time"
), class = "factor")

dput(head(test$colA))
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("I am currently using (least once over the last 2 weeks)", "I have never tried nor used"
"I have tried or used at some point in time"
), class = "factor")
```

I can see there is a difference from: `c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)` to `c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)` . So I guess here is the key, although I don't know what does it exactly mean.

Comment: I cannot recreate your output, for me it works just fine. Maybe utilize `dput()` to share a snippet of your `data.frame`.

Comment: Post reproducible example `dput(head(train))` and `dput(head(test))`

Comment: even with your edit, I still can't reproduce your error